# Updating wrong integer value in increment mysql Codeigniter 4

Tags: mysql, sql-update, codeigniter-4

I want to increase integer value in blog post view. I used this code top of the controller in Codeigniter4:

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table('blog');
$builder->set('view', 'view+1', FALSE);
$builder->where('id', $id);
$builder->update();
```

It is updating ..2,4,6,8.. in database instead of 1,2,3,4 while refreshing page. If I use 'view+2', updating 2,6,10,14.. But why? Whats wrong with this basic math to compute?

I spent whole day to solve, but not finding any solution.

```
$view = "Get previous view value from db";
$data['view'] = $view + 1;
                
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table('blog');
$builder->where('id', $id);
$builder->update($data);
```

Getting same result with this query.

Comment: The script is probably executed more than once.

Comment: Check your access log to see how many times the script is called.

Comment: Yes, the script is running more than once.

Answer (score 0):

The script is running anyway more than once. I've made a temporary solution to run this script once by a trick with computer after thinking too much about my innocent code. I used session Tempdata with 5 second validity timing to run the script once.

```
$session = \Config\Services::session(); // This line added very top of the code
if($session->single_view == null){
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
        $builder = $db->table('blog');
        $builder->set('view', 'view+1', FALSE);
        $builder->where('id', $id);
        $builder->update();
          }
$session->setTempdata('single_view', '1', 5);
```

At first, the session is null and immediate after the code session is not null, so the script running once, and adding single view nicely.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using type (int) or intval($view) when you get previous value from database?

```
$view = "Get previous view value from db";
$data['view'] = intval($view) + 1;
                
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table('blog');
$builder->where('id', $id);
$builder->update($data);
```

Comment: I tried this but the script is actually running more than once for unknown reason.

Comment: omg, i shocked when you mentioning your code running more than once for 'unknown reason'. there's no unknown reason in code, its your code, you should knowing your code.

Comment: I know my code well, I did not write any code which run the PHP company more than once. I knew and it supposed to be run any php script once. Anyway, I gave lots of time to solve this unknown issue and made a temporary solution. I will check again what was the problem in free time. Your suggestion helped me to check in different angle.